# CSS Layout Issues on IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on a site and have it mostly laid out how I want it, but I'm running into some formatting issues with Internet Explorer 9 (IE9). I've dug all through the forums reading a lot of positioning of elements, and z-index and I'm coming up blank on how to fix my issue. If I test my site in Chrome, Firefox, IE11 everything looks fine.

However, in IE9 (not sure about 10) my Overlay div is hidden behind the images. The site I'm having trouble with can be found at http://ktwu.trilionstudios.com/wp-content/themes/ktwu/csstest.html I'm currently testing with a static page, but eventually this will be moved into a regular template and content generated dynamically.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">

/*****CSS RESET*******/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; }
body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
:focus { outline: 0; }
ins { text-decoration: none; }
del { text-decoration: line-through; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

#slider4 ul, #slider4 li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#slider4 li {
    height: 345px;
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#homevideo .leftvideo{
    position: relative;
    height: 345px;
    width: 650px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#homevideo a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#homevideo .leftvideo img{
    position: relative;
    height: 345px;
    width: 650px;
}

#homevideo .rightvideogroup{
    float: right;   
    width: 300px;
}

#homevideo .rightvideo1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 168px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}

#homevideo .rightvideo2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 168px;
    width: 300px;
}

#homevideo .rightvideo1 img{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 168px;
}

#homevideo .rightvideo2 img{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 168px;
}

#homevideo h3{
        clear: both;
    }

#homevideo .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0% 0%;
    width: 100%;
}



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="homevideo">
            <div id="slider4">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="leftvideo">
                            <a href="http://watch.ktwu.org/video/2365060152"><img src="http://image.pbs.org/video-assets/KTWU/ktwu-special-programs/93697/images/Mezzanine_323.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <h4><a href="http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/masterpiece/">Sunflower Journeys</a></h4>
                                <h3><a href="http://watch.ktwu.org/video/2365143420">Wood, Brick, and Stone</a></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rightvideogroup">
                            <div class="rightvideo1">
                                <a href="http://watch.ktwu.org/video/2365143420"><img src="http://image.pbs.org/video-assets/pbs/masterpiece/109334/images/Mezzanine_171.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                <div class="overlay">
                                    <h4><a href="http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/masterpiece/">Masterpiece</a></h4>
                                    <h3><a href="http://watch.ktwu.org/video/2365143420">Downton Abbey Season 4, Episode 1</a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightvideo2">
                                <a href="http://watch.ktwu.org/video/2365145009"><img src="http://image.pbs.org/video-assets/KTWU/ktwu-ive-got-issues/109621/images/Mezzanine_142.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                <div class="overlay">
                                    <h4><a href="http://www.ktwu.org/productions/ive-got-issues/">KTWU I've Got Issues</a></h4>
                                    <h3><a href="http://watch.ktwu.org/video/2365145009">Philippine Calamity</a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

David

Comment: please paste code here...not the url!! :)

Comment: we would like to see the code.... if we have to click on every url posted, our pc would become a spyware container

Comment: I added the code inline here, sorry about that, just didn't want to clutter up the page if I didn't have to. :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you have added a z-index to your **#homevideo .overlay** class.

Try:

```
#homevideo .overlay {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
bottom: 5%;
left: 0px;
padding: 0% 0%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
}
```

You should also add a doctype declaration at the top of the page.  I would suggest using the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      ...
```

Comment: I've just tested this, and it's still not working. From some of the reading I've done it mentioned IE being really picky about parent elements and the grouping of z-index, and I've wondered if that might be part of my problem that the Overlay div isn't in the same parent group as the image that it's sitting behind, but I haven't found anything that will help bring it to the front of the page.

Comment: Add the DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your page (i.e. before the <html> tag).  <!DOCTYPE html> (answer updated above)